# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to bind the datasources?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

While deploying a custom war to a WebSphere Liberty profile I get the following exception:

> Class org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver not found

I have created and configured the databases by following:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_configuring_liberty_profile_for_derby_manually.html

And edited the server.xml file by following:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_configuring_liberty_profile_manually.html

In the web.xml of the generated custom war the resource references for the datasources have these values:

```
<res-ref-name>jdbc/WorklightDS</res-ref-name>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/WorklightReportsDS</res-ref-name>
```

But the datasources defined in the server xml have these others:

```
<dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false" statementCacheSize="10">
<dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false" statementCacheSize="10">
```

Anyway I have tried changing the datasource jndi and I get the same exception.

I have also tried to add to the worklight.properties file the properties wl.db.jndi.name and wl.reports.db.jndi.name without success. I supose these properties are not longer valid in WL6.0.

Also tried adding a file ibm-web-bnd.xml to the generated war.

I guess the problem is related to the binding between the application and the Liberty profile datasources.

The only way I have been able to deploy the custom war is setting the Derby databases in the workligh.properties file.

```
wl.db.url=jdbc:derby:C:/WebSphere/Worklight60DBs/WRKLGHT;create=true
wl.reports.db.url=jdbc:derby:C:/WebSphere/Worklight60DBs/WLREPORT;create=true
wl.db.username=WORKLIGHT
```

For the error this is my server.xml:

```
<featureManager>                      
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>        
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>        
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>    
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>       
    <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>                                     
</featureManager>                     

<application id="CaixaProject" name="CaixaProject" location="CaixaProject.war" type="war">   
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">                                                        
        <commonLibrary>                                                                          
            <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>                      
        </commonLibrary>                                                                         
    </classloader>                                                                               
</application>                                                                                   

<webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false"/>  

<library id="DerbyLib">                                                                                               
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/derby" includes="derby.jar"/>
</library>                          

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false" statementCacheSize="10">                                                                           
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DerbyLib" javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource"/>                                                                
    <properties.derby.embedded databaseName="C:/WebSphere/Worklight60DBs/WRKLGHT" user="WORKLIGHT" shutdownDatabase="false" connectionAttributes="upgrade=true"/>
    <connectionManager connectionTimeout="180" maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="1" reapTime="180" maxIdleTime="1800" agedTimeout="7200" purgePolicy="EntirePool" /> 
</dataSource>    

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false" statementCacheSize="10">                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DerbyLib" javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource"/>                                
    <properties.derby.embedded databaseName="C:/WebSphere/Worklight60DBs/WLREPORT" user="WORKLIGHT" shutdownDatabase="false" connectionAttributes="upgrade=true"/>
    <connectionManager connectionTimeout="180" maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="1" reapTime="180" maxIdleTime="1800" agedTimeout="7200" purgePolicy="EntirePool" />  
</dataSource>
```

And the only properties I have modified in the worklight.properties file:

```
publicWorkLightHostname
publicWorkLightProtocol
publicWorkLightPort
```

How can I deploy a custom war to a Liberty profile using datasources?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is a misleading message. It is related to jndi configuration.

Your jndi references should include CaixaProject in the name
like this in the server.xml

```
<dataSource jndiName="CaixaProject/jdbc/WorklightDS"
<dataSource jndiName="CaixaProject/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS"
```

and inside the web.xml is should be like this

```
<res-ref-name>CaixaProject/jdbc/WorklightDS</res-ref-name>
<res-ref-name>CaixaProject/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS</res-ref-name>
```

Referece for you [Worklight 6.0 does not start on Liberty - HSQLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060671/worklight-6-0-does-not-start-on-liberty-hsqldb)

Comment: You should not touch web.xml

Comment: Hi. I could make it work using the application id in the dataSource jndiName. (CaixaProject/jdbc/WorklightDS) and without modifing the web.xml. Just one more comment, other side effect I was suffering was that I downloaded a Derby version grater than the derby.jar version configured for ProcessCenter. I used the newer derby to create the worklight and report databases but I was using the older jar in the server.xml. It causes the application not to start also.